# Which unsupervised learning algorithm can be used for peaks detection?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, unsupervised-learning, anomaly-detection

So, I have a dataset that has around 1388 unique products and I have to do unsupervised learning on them in order to find anomalies (high/low peaks).

The data below just represents one product. The `ContextID` is the product number, and the `StepID` indicates different stages in the making of the product.

```
    ContextID   BacksGas_Flow_sccm  StepID  Time_ms
427 7290057 1.7578125   1   09:20:15.273
428 7290057 1.7578125   1   09:20:15.513
429 7290057 1.953125    2   09:20:15.744
430 7290057 1.85546875  2   09:20:16.814
431 7290057 1.7578125   2   09:20:17.833
432 7290057 1.7578125   2   09:20:18.852
433 7290057 1.7578125   2   09:20:19.872
434 7290057 1.7578125   2   09:20:20.892
435 7290057 1.7578125   2   09:20:22.42
436 7290057 16.9921875  5   09:20:23.82
437 7290057 46.19140625 5   09:20:24.102
438 7290057 46.19140625 5   09:20:25.122
439 7290057 46.6796875  5   09:20:26.142
440 7290057 46.6796875  5   09:20:27.162
441 7290057 46.6796875  5   09:20:28.181
442 7290057 46.6796875  5   09:20:29.232
443 7290057 46.6796875  5   09:20:30.361
444 7290057 46.6796875  5   09:20:31.381
445 7290057 46.6796875  5   09:20:32.401
446 7290057 46.6796875  5   09:20:33.431
447 7290057 46.6796875  5   09:20:34.545
448 7290057 46.6796875  5   09:20:34.761
449 7290057 46.6796875  5   09:20:34.972
450 7290057 46.6796875  5   09:20:36.50
451 7290057 46.6796875  5   09:20:37.120
452 7290057 46.6796875  7   09:20:38.171
453 7290057 46.6796875  7   09:20:39.261
454 7290057 46.6796875  7   09:20:40.280
455 7290057 46.6796875  12  09:20:41.429
456 7290057 46.6796875  12  09:20:42.449
457 7290057 46.6796875  12  09:20:43.469
458 7290057 46.6796875  12  09:20:44.499
459 7290057 46.6796875  12  09:20:45.559
460 7290057 46.6796875  12  09:20:45.689
461 7290057 47.16796875 12  09:20:46.710
462 7290057 46.6796875  12  09:20:47.749
463 7290057 46.6796875  15  09:20:48.868
464 7290057 46.6796875  15  09:20:49.889
465 7290057 46.6796875  16  09:20:50.910
466 7290057 46.6796875  16  09:20:51.938
467 7290057 24.21875    19  09:20:52.999
468 7290057 38.76953125 19  09:20:54.27
469 7290057 80.46875    19  09:20:55.68
470 7290057 72.75390625 19  09:20:56.128
471 7290057 59.5703125  19  09:20:57.247
472 7290057 63.671875   19  09:20:58.278
473 7290057 70.5078125  19  09:20:59.308
474 7290057 71.875  19  09:21:00.337
475 7290057 69.82421875 19  09:21:01.358
476 7290057 69.23828125 19  09:21:02.408
477 7290057 69.23828125 19  09:21:03.548
478 7290057 72.4609375  19  09:21:04.597
479 7290057 73.4375 19  09:21:05.615
480 7290057 73.4375 19  09:21:06.647
481 7290057 73.4375 19  09:21:07.675
482 7290057 73.4375 19  09:21:08.697
483 7290057 73.4375 19  09:21:09.727
484 7290057 74.21875    19  09:21:10.796
485 7290057 75.1953125  19  09:21:11.827
486 7290057 75.1953125  19  09:21:12.846
487 7290057 75.1953125  19  09:21:13.865
488 7290057 75.1953125  19  09:21:14.886
489 7290057 75.1953125  19  09:21:15.907
490 7290057 75.9765625  19  09:21:16.936
491 7290057 75.9765625  19  09:21:17.975
492 7290057 75.9765625  19  09:21:18.997
493 7290057 75.9765625  19  09:21:20.27
494 7290057 75.9765625  19  09:21:21.55
495 7290057 75.9765625  19  09:21:22.75
496 7290057 75.9765625  19  09:21:23.95
497 7290057 76.85546875 19  09:21:24.204
498 7290057 76.85546875 19  09:21:25.225
499 7290057 76.85546875 19  09:21:25.957
500 7290057 76.85546875 19  09:21:26.984
501 7290057 75.9765625  19  09:21:27.995
502 7290057 75.9765625  19  09:21:29.2
503 7290057 76.7578125  19  09:21:30.13
504 7290057 76.7578125  19  09:21:31.33
505 7290057 76.7578125  19  09:21:32.59
506 7290057 76.7578125  19  09:21:33.142
507 7290057 76.7578125  19  09:21:34.153
508 7290057 75.87890625 19  09:21:34.986
509 7290057 75.87890625 19  09:21:35.131
510 7290057 75.87890625 19  09:21:35.272
511 7290057 75.87890625 19  09:21:35.451
512 7290057 76.7578125  19  09:21:36.524
513 7290057 76.7578125  19  09:21:37.651
514 7290057 76.7578125  19  09:21:38.695
515 7290057 76.7578125  19  09:21:39.724
516 7290057 76.7578125  19  09:21:40.760
517 7290057 76.7578125  19  09:21:41.783
518 7290057 76.7578125  19  09:21:42.802
519 7290057 76.7578125  19  09:21:43.822
520 7290057 76.7578125  19  09:21:44.862
521 7290057 76.7578125  19  09:21:45.884
522 7290057 76.7578125  19  09:21:46.912
523 7290057 76.7578125  19  09:21:47.933
524 7290057 76.7578125  19  09:21:48.952
525 7290057 76.7578125  19  09:21:49.972
526 7290057 76.7578125  19  09:21:51.72
527 7290057 77.5390625  19  09:21:52.290
528 7290057 77.5390625  19  09:21:52.92
529 7290057 77.5390625  19  09:21:53.361
530 7290057 77.5390625  19  09:21:54.435
531 7290057 76.66015625 19  09:21:55.602
532 7290057 76.66015625 19  09:21:56.621
533 7290057 72.94921875 22  09:21:57.652
534 7290057 3.90625 24  09:21:58.749
535 7290057 2.5390625   24  09:21:59.801
536 7290057 2.1484375   24  09:22:00.882
537 7290057 2.05078125  24  09:22:01.259
538 7290057 2.1484375   24  09:22:01.53
539 7290057 1.953125    24  09:22:02.281
540 7290057 1.953125    24  09:22:03.311
541 7290057 2.1484375   24  09:22:04.331
542 7290057 2.1484375   24  09:22:05.351
543 7290057 1.953125    24  09:22:06.432
544 7290057 1.85546875  24  09:22:07.519
545 7290057 1.7578125   24  09:22:08.549
546 7290057 1.85546875  24  09:22:09.710
547 7290057 1.7578125   24  09:22:10.738
548 7290057 1.85546875  24  09:22:11.798
549 7290057 1.953125    24  09:22:12.820
550 7290057 1.85546875  1   09:22:13.610
551 7290057 1.85546875  1   09:22:14.629
552 7290057 1.953125    1   09:22:15.649
553 7290057 1.85546875  2   09:22:16.679
554 7290057 1.85546875  2   09:22:17.709
555 7290057 1.85546875  2   09:22:18.729
556 7290057 1.953125    2   09:22:19.748
557 7290057 1.85546875  2   09:22:20.768
558 7290057 1.7578125   3   09:22:21.788
559 7290057 1.7578125   3   09:22:22.808
560 7290057 1.85546875  3   09:22:23.829
561 7290057 1.953125    3   09:22:24.848
562 7290057 1.85546875  3   09:22:25.898
563 7290057 1.953125    3   09:22:27.39
564 7290057 1.953125    3   09:22:28.66
565 7290057 1.7578125   3   09:22:29.87
566 7290057 1.85546875  3   09:22:30.108
567 7290057 1.7578125   3   09:22:31.129
568 7290057 1.953125    3   09:22:32.147
569 7290057 1.85546875  3   09:22:33.187
```

I use the following code to plot a graph.

**Code:**

```
lineplot = X.loc[X['ContextID'] == 7290057]
x_axis = lineplot.values[:,3]
y_axis = lineplot.values[:,1]

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(x_axis, y_axis)
```

and the **graph:**
[image]

In this graph, the peaks (marked in red circles) are the anomalies that need to be detected.

And when I have a graph like this: No anomalies must be caught since there are no undesirable peaks.

[image]

I tried using `OneClassSVM`, but I am somehow not satisfied with the results.

I would like to know which unsupervised learning algorithm can be used for such a task at hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your anomalies are simply peaks, why should you be using machine learning methods? You could use peak detection algorithms for the purpose.

If you still insist on ML, isolation forest is a good try.

Comment: For completeness and for people not familiar with them, maybe you can suggest 1-2 concrete "peak detection algorithms" that could be used to solve the problem.

Comment: Sure ! One simple method is finding difference between consecutive samples and if the difference suddenly increases compared to the previous set (say 5 samples) of differences you detect a peak. The other more robust method is perform the Discrete Wavelet transform of the data, square the results and find values that are twice higher than the median.